# Multidimensional Analysis Using BO

Tags: business-objects

I developed an Ad-Hoc report for my user. The report has 65 dimensions and 3 facts. Now the user wants to have the output in BO in 5 mins and the expected lines in the report ,for any combination of the dimensions, is 100k.

I created a database table with all 65 dimensions and aggregated the facts by grouping by the 65 dimensions. But when the user selects few dimensions and the facts, the report takes a lot of time. Is there a way I can achieve the SLA of 5 mins for the ad-hoc report?

The report is a simple list report and I don't know what my user will achieve by looking at 100k records in the report.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a solution, but might be a good workaround. You could uncheck 'Refresh on open', and then schedule the generation of the report in the CMC (if you have access) for example during the night. This way you don't have the latest data in your report, but if that is not needed, this might be a suitable solution to avoid long running times upon request.